# Excel VBA Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) cannot open a file with capital letter extension

Tags: excel, vba, file, ms-office

I'm trying to open an Excel file in Excel VBA. However, I cannot open files with capital letter extension (e.g: abcd.XLSX). Files with lowercase extension work well(e.g: abcd.xlsx) with the below code.

Can someone please help me how to make it work?

```
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xls; *.xlsb; *.XLS; *.XLSX; *.XLSM; *.XLSB", 1
    If .Show = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
  End With
```

Comment: yes, abcd.XLSX has no problem.. I can open the file when I switched the XLSX extension to .xlsx . My Excel is 2016 edition.

Comment: AFAIK excel always saves with the extension in lower case - if you have files that are being produced by a different program then make sure that program is also using a lower case extension...